# Can a table in SQL have multiple columns as foreign keys that refer only to one primary key of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

For instance, table Companies has columns company_name, first_contact, second_contact and table contacts have columns id(PK), name, phone. Can a table (companies) in SQL have multiple columns as foreign keys that refer only to one primary key of another table (contacts)?

Comment: There is no problem with that. Probably the most common example is a `messages` table with `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` both referencing the `users` table.

Comment: YES and NO. You could but would probably have to throw away some features such as on delete cascade.

Comment: @P.Salmon - What's the problem with `ON DELETE CASCADE`? It should work IMHO.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel If you had FKs on company and first_contact with on delete cascade on both and you then deleted company in contacts how would mysql react? I haven;t tried it so I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: @P.Salmon When you delete a contact, all companies that are refering that contact in `first_contact` or `second_contact` will be deleted. That you probably don't want that - is another question. But I don't see why that shouldn't work.

Comment: What really worth of having same PK value in 2 or more column?

Comment: Another common implementation of this is multiple references to a `DATE` table or dimension. Happens all the time.

Comment: This strikes me as being an unnormalized database, i.e. it is not even in first normal form since it has repeating attributes (first_contact and second_contact).Why wouldn't you have a Companies_contacts table where each row has two foreign keys, one to the Companies table and one to the contacts table. This is assuming, possibly incorrectly, that a person can be a contact for multiple companies. If not, just add to the contacts table a foreign key to the Companies table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here's an example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Contacts (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE Companies (id INT PRIMARY KEY, company_name TEXT,
    -> first_contact INT, second_contact INT,
    -> FOREIGN KEY (first_contact) REFERENCES Contacts(id),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (second_contact) REFERENCES Contacts(id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

But it would be more common to design the database another way, with a third table instead of the two foreign keys in Companies:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE CompanyContacts (
    -> contact_id INT NOT NULL,
    -> company_id INT NOT NULL,
    -> is_primary BOOL NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (contact_id, company_id),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES Contacts(id),
    -> FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES Companies(id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

Some advantages:

- You aren't limited to two contacts per company.
- You can search for a contact more simply — instead of searching if a contact occurs as either the first_contact or second_contact, you just search for it in CompanyContacts.contact_id. It's easier to optimize that query with an index.

Some disadvantages:

- No way to make a constraint to make at least one contact mandatory. You can do this by declaring first_contact as `NOT NULL` in your design, but there's no SQL constraint that requires a row to exist in the third table for each company.
- If you're put off by JOIN queries, this might not be attractive. But I recommend you get comfortable with doing JOINs when you have many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You'd essentially have several one-to-one relationships from Companies to Contacts.

When querying the data, you'd have to join in the Contacts table multiple times (once per column that is a foreign key)

```sql
select *
from Companies c
join Contacts contact1 on c.first_contact=contact1.id
join Contacts contact2 on c.second_contact=contact2.id
```